# Html in visual studio code, Image and font color are not shown on the website

Tags: html, webshop

```
   *That's the file index.html*

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link href="styles\styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text\css">
          <title>24/7-Clanshop.de</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>24/7-Clanshop</h1>
          <p>The official shop for your 24/7 streetstyle!</p>
          <ol>
            <li>Hoodies</li>
            <li>Jogginghosen</li>
            <li>Socken</li>
            <li>Accessoires</li>
          </ol>
          <p>Look up to the <a href="https:\\www.youtube.com\channel\UCcj38MW1dBr_xB0m4T56UbA">Channel</a></p>
          <img src="pictures\testpicture.jpg" alt="My test picture">
          </body>
        </html>

*That's the file styles.css*

p, li, h1 {
  color:#ff0000;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**When i run this programm, neither the picture nor the font color can be displayed. Is it due to my browsersettings or am I overlooking something completely different?**

Comment: Willkommen. Please translate (and post) your question in English.

Comment: Thank for your hint. I translated it.

Comment: Please translate the title of your question too

Comment: `styles\styles.css` » `styles/styles.css` it needs a forward slash.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: path is wrong in your link and img, use either relative path or absolute